Can pain be "binding"?
I am a teacher and a student used the phrase binding pain. I wasn't able to find anything about this phrase online and am not sure if it is correct or understandable.
I know that "shared pain" can connect people but can it also "bind" them together? If it can, then "binding pain" sounds wrong to me because of the adjective "binding" (obligatory), but is that correct? If so, is there a more suitable collocation?

Where did you see this phrase? Could it have been a typo for "blinding"?

Why are you asking this? Have you seen the phrase? Or are you looking for a phrase with a particular meaning ("shared pain" is far more common)?

Shared suffering can bond people (can cause people to bond) together…

I am a teacher and a student has used it. I was not able to find a satisfactory answer by consulting collocations dictionaries or online corpora.

You could say, metaphorically, that a shared experience 'binds' people together, but it would be odd to talk about 'binding pain'; not because of the sense 'legally binding', but because it's stretching the metaphor a bit too far to use 'binding' as an adjective like that. You could say "The experience of pain formed a bond between them".
